# Selecting the number of times an ID field appears in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database that I'm pulling info from, and it's been determined that I need to remove records that have no orders. It turns out that we have customers in the database that have no orders, and we don't want to select those.

My original query is this:

```
USE AspDotNetStoreFrontB2C;
SELECT TOP (100) 
    [c].[CustomerID]
  , [c].[FirstName]
  , [c].[LastName]
  , [c].[Email]
  , [c].[Phone]
  , [a].[Company]
  , [a].[Address1]
  , [a].[Address2]
  , [a].[Suite]
  , [a].[City]
  , [a].State
  , [a].[Zip]
  , [a].[Country]
FROM [Customer] AS [c]
JOIN [Address] AS [a]
     ON [c].[CustomerID] = [a].[CustomerID];
```

I want to do something like

```
count(select o.CustomerID from Orders where o.CustomerID=c.CustomerID)
```

However SQL Server Management Studio doesn't like this saying that c.CustomerID cannot be bound.

How can I modify this query to get a count of how many orders the customer being selected has made?

Comment: join Customer and Orders table using CustomerId, then select Customerid,count(CustomerId) group by CustomerId.

Comment: Where is your `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Your requirements contradict themselves. At one point you want to not return customers that have not ordered. But at the end you want to get the count of orders. Do you want the count of orders AND eliminate those that have no orders?

Comment: I'll work on being more clear. The issue has already been solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want customers that have placed an order, then use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT TOP (100)
       c.CustomerID,
       c.FirstName,
       c.LastName,
       c.Email,
       c.Phone,
       a.Company,
       a.Address1,
       a.Address2,
       a.Suite,
       a.City,
       a.State,
       a.Zip,
       a.Country
FROM Customer c
     JOIN Address a ON c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Orders O
              WHERE O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID)
ORDER BY (SELECT NULL); --Whoop whoop, 100 random rows
```

I did comment this under the question, but to put in the answer, I have added an `ORDER BY`. If you provide `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` then you are effectively saying to the Server "Return 100 Random rows". I have used `(SELECT NULL)`, as I don't know what order you want your rows, so you'll need to change that.

Comment: Excellent! This works! I found another issue for the overall project, but that's going to be more a of a management decision.

Comment: 2min to go to accept

Comment: why order by (select null)?

Comment: @Nadeem I already explain why in the answer. See the paragraph under the SQL.

Comment: @Larnu saw it. It will load top 100 rows instead of random 100 rows if used without order by clause

Comment: @Nadeem huh? `SELECT TOP 100` with or without `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` will return 100 random rows.